# Expand a grouped value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'prod':['A','A','A','B','B'],'quant':[2,3,4,3,1]}
    prod    quant
0   A       2
1   A       3
2   A       4
3   B       3
4   B       1
```

And I want to aggregate the values by `prod` but to keep the values as a new column. This is the expected data frame:

```py
    prod    quant    added_gr
0   A       2        9
1   A       3        9
2   A       4        9
3   B       3        4
4   B       1        4
```

I tried this

```py
ds['added_gr'] = ds.groupby('prod')['quant'].sum()
```

But it returns me a column with all NaNs. Please, could you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `ds.groupby('prod')['quant'].transform('sum')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform(np.sum)`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'prod':['A','A','A','B','B'],'quant':[2,3,4,3,1]}
df['added_gr'] = df.groupby('prod')['quant'].transform(np.sum)
```